# Angular access to generic ID

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have some code which adds new input and I need after some time for example 3 seconds input to hide. Problem is how to hide each separate input after 3 seconds of display each.

In html code I have:

```
id="{{ 'inputNum-' + $id }}"
```

In Javascript:

```
$timeout(function () {
      document.getElementsById('commentNum-' + $id).css('display', 'none');
}, 3000);
```

[https://jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/wisla/v60wn5s7/1/)

Comment: Is this old Angular or new AngularJS?

Comment: It's AngularJS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to manipulate `DOM`, the AngularJS-way to do this is to write your [custom `directive`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```js
(function(){
  'use strict';
  
  angular
    .module('inputsApp', [])
    .controller('InputsController', InputsController)
    .directive('hideMe', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
      return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          var timeOut = $timeout(function () {
            angular.element(element).css('display', 'none');
          }, new Number(attrs.hideMe));
          scope.$on('$destroy', function(){
            if (timeOut) $timeout.cancel(timeOut);
          });
        }
      }
    }])
  
  InputsController.$inject = ['$scope', '$timeout'];
  
  function InputsController($scope, $timeout) {
    var vm = this;
    
    // Current input.
    vm.input = {};

    // Array where inputs will be.
    vm.inputs = [];

    // Run when input is submited.
    vm.addInput = function() {

      vm.inputs.push( vm.input );
      vm.input = {};

      // Reset clases of the form after submit.
      $scope.form.$setPristine();
    }

  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><div class="inputs-app" ng-app="inputsApp" ng-controller="InputsController as cmntCtrl">

  <div class="inputs">
    
    <!-- Comment -->
    <div class="input" hide-me="2000" ng-repeat="input in cmntCtrl.inputs" id="{{ 'inputNum-' + $id }}">

      <!-- Comment Box -->
      <div class="input-box">
        <div class="input-text">{{ input.text }}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

    <!-- From -->
  <div class="input-form">

    <form class="form" name="form" ng-submit="form.$valid && cmntCtrl.addInput()" novalidate>
      <div class="form-row">
        <textarea
                  class="input"
                  ng-model="cmntCtrl.input.text"
                  placeholder="Add input..."
                  required></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-row">
        <input type="submit" value="Add input">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: `!!hideMeTimeOut ? hideMeTimeOut : 0` - oh my.

Comment: @raina77ow agreed, doesn't make any sense

Comment: !!something is shortcut  way of checking if something is undefined (if it is this is false if it's not this is true) Less readable but faster to type

Comment: Added this "extra" check, but this is useless since `$timeout` handles this. The comment "oh my" doesn't say much about what was really BAD with this `!!` :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to think Angular way here: instead of modifying the UI directly, modify the model instead - and let framework do work for you. For example:

```
  vm.addInput = function() {
      var inputToAdd = vm.input;
      vm.inputs.push(inputToAdd);

      $timeout(function () {
        var indexOfInput = vm.inputs.indexOf(inputToAdd);
        vm.inputs.splice(indexOfInput, 1);
      }, 3000);      

      vm.input = {};
      // ... the rest of code
  }
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/p1mw5221/). And if you don't actually those inputs to be dropped from the list, again, modify their attributes.

JS:

```
  $timeout(function () {
    var indexOfInput = vm.inputs.indexOf(inputToAdd);
    vm.inputs[indexOfInput].hidden = true;
  }, 3000);
```

Template:

```
  <div class="input" ng-hide="input.hidden" 
       ng-repeat="input in cmntCtrl.inputs" id="{{ 'inputNum-' + $id }}">
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jszf0090/). With this approach, all the items are still in DOM (so it's exactly equivalent to what you tried to do). You might probably prefer using `ng-if` instead of `ng-hide`, dropping them from DOM completely.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Angular's binding system.

1. add a property

   `vm.showCommentBox = true;`
2. change to set the boolean

   `$timeout(function () {
         vm.showCommentBox = false;
       }, 3000);`
3. add the binding to your html
   `<div class="input-box" ng-if="showCommentBox">`

Answer (score 0):

General advice with Angular is doing things Angular way (it's convention over configuration framework).

And the Angular way would be to bind visibility with **ng-show** and **ng-hide** or existence in DOM via **ng-if** and then MODIFY THE MODEL NOT influence the DOM directly.

Alternatively, you can alter between element having a class and not with **ng-class**. And then separate styling in CSS file.

Depending on what you need: (choose class names yourself)

```
.hidden{
visibility: hidden;
}
```

or

```
.not-displayed{
display: none;
}
```